# Tweets and followers fetching app with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, backend

I'm trying to build an app in Python with Google App Engine that fetches followers of specific accounts and then their tweets. I'm basing it on [this template](https://github.com/amygdala/gae-dataflow/blob/master/sdk_launch/README.md) and changing it to adapt it to what I need.

The issue at the moment is that when I try to fetch followers, I get an `DeadlineExceededError` due to the Twitter API waiting time.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676264/whats-the-correct-approach-for-a-twitter-application-on-google-app-engine) post on how to fix the same problem and I think that in my case the best solution would be to use backends, but I noticed that they are deprecated.

Does someone know how I can achieve the same result without the deprecated module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options that you can use for long-running tasks:

- [Use GAE Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/): GAE provides push and pull queues which allow you to do work asynchronously outside of the individual request.
- [Use Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-cloud-pub-sub-long-running-tasks): A type of pull queue, this would allow your App Engine app to publish a message every time you wanted fetch followers or fetch tweets. The subscriber would then take the message from the queue, perform a long-running task, and then put the result into some datastore.
- [Use GAE Services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#services): This would allow you to create a background service and [manually scale it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) to run as long as you need.

Comment: Do you know if there is a sample code for the use of services to have some kind of starting point?

Comment: Services are really the same as any other app, they just have an additional `service: your-service-id` in the `app.yaml` and can be scaled independently. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48684042/328036

Answer (score 1):

Backends (modules) have been deprecated in favor of Services:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/an-overview-of-app-engine

For the Service you want to be able to handle requests longer than 60 seconds, set it to Manual Scaling.  Then, a request can run for up to 24 hours (or until you shut it down).  See:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling

Of course, your costs may go up with long running instances and request.

Comment: Do you know if there is a sample code for the use of services to have some kind of starting point?